# ROS Answers SE migration: ButtonEvent

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using ROS Hydro
I wanted to subscribe to kobuki_msgs::ButtonEvent using roscpp client.
However, the compiler does not recognize this event and throws an error message

`error: ‘ButtonEvent’ in namespace ‘kobuki_msgs’ does not name a type`

I already successfully subscribed to all others events like `kobuki_msgs::BumperEvent`, `kobuki_msgs::CliffEvent`, but I am not able to use `kobuki_msgs::ButtonEvent`

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks
Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210165/buttonevent/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2015-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you included the header file "kobuki_msgs/ButtonEvent.h"? It's a different header file than for `BumperEvent` and `CliffEvent`.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on 2015-05-29**:
Thank you for the answer. It was actually missing. Now, everything works after I included the header file. In fact, I was including the other events header files in a superclass, and I did not figure out in the sub-class that the header file of Button is missing.

Thank you